# Type body created with compilation error

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ordbms

customer_ty object I have created has a nested table including

```
CREATE TYPE deposit_ty as object(
depNo number,
depCategory ref depcategory_ty,
amount number,
period number
)
/

CREATE TYPE deposit_tbl as table of deposit_ty
/

CREATE TYPE customer_ty as object(
custId varchar2(4),
custName varchar2(10),
address address_ty,
dob date,
deposits deposit_tbl
)
/
```

I have written a code to compute the total amount deposited by each client. Here is the code I've written;

```
alter type customer_ty
add member function totDeposits return number cascade
/

create or replace type body customer_ty as
member function totDeposits 
return number is
total number;
BEGIN
    select sum(d.amount) into total
    from table(self.deposits) d;
    group by self.custId,self.custName
    return total;
END totDeposits;
END;
/
```

But I get a warning saying that the "type body created with compilation errors". What can I do to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `show errors` immediately after you get the 'created with compilation errors' message, you'll see something like:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "GROUP" when expecting one of the following:
```

You can also query the `user_errors` or `all_errors` view to see the outstanding errors against any PL/SQL objects.

In this case it's a simple typo; you have the semicolon in the wrong place; instead of:

```
select sum(d.amount) into total
from table(self.deposits) d;
group by self.custId,self.custName
```

it should be:

```
select sum(d.amount) into total
from table(self.deposits) d
group by self.custId,self.custName;
```

In your version the `... d;` is terminating that SQL statement - which would be invalid now because that truncated statement doesn't have a group by clause; but it doesn't get as far as complaining about that because it sees the `group by ...` as a separate statement, and that isn't the start of anything PL/SQL recognises as a query, statement, control loop etc., so it gives up.

Comment: I had no idea how to put semicolon in functions. Thank you for the explanation. Now it's working and I have better understanding about functions.

Comment: A semicolon terminates a statement, which can be a SQL statement, a PL/SQL a variable assignment, control construct, etc. The group-by is part of the select statement - there shouldn't be a semicolon in the middle of a single SQL statement.